# Make VS Code to execute python script in an already running terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

If I have a terminal already running with the required variables exported, is there a way to tell VS Code: "when I press run, start the script in this terminal, instead of starting a new one" while also allow debugging using vs code breakpoints.

Comment: Is there a detailed picture description? When I run different files in the process of using vscode, they will only run in the default terminal, and they are all on the same terminal.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I want the editor to run the script on an already running external terminal, with launch.json i can run the script on the integrated terminal, the run tab or vs starts a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

According to your supplementary instructions, what you want is to be able to run scripts on external terminals.

This is actually explained in the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).:

[image]

We could change the line "console:" as the following in launch.json:

```
"console": "externalTerminal",
```

Comment: Yes but the issue with 'externalTerminal' is that every execution starts a new terminal, is there a way to make the run button equivalent to 'python script.py' in an already running terminal?

Comment: For now, this should not be possible